# In Linux: How to repeat multiple lines in a file in the same order?

Tags: linux, bash, text

The input file contains below lines:

```
a
b
c
```

I want the output as(n times):

```
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

I've tried below command but it doesn't maintain the order

```
while read line; do for i in {1..4}; do echo "$line"; done; done < file
```

but the output is

```
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

Comment: what about simply appending the file n times, like `cat file1 >> file2` in a loop?

Answer (score 3):

Using `seq` with `xargs`:

```
seq 2 | xargs -Inone cat file
```

Comment: Regardless than the `seq` isn't available on all systems, the solution works and solves the problem. Could the downvoter add an explanation? +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be

```
#multicat count filename(s)
multicat() {
        local count=$1
        shift
        for((i=0;i < $count; i++)) {
                cat "$@"
        }
}

multicat 3 abc          # outputs the "abc" file 3 times
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf` and `brace expansion` can be used to repeat a string N times, which can then be passed as input to `cat` which does its job of **concatenate**

```
$ printf "file %.s" {1..4}
file file file file $ 

$ cat $(printf "file %.s" {1..4})
a
b
c
a
b
c
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

With `perl`, if file is small enough for memory requirements to be slurped whole

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $_ x 2' file 
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 0):

A small solution for printing `file` 3 times:

```
cat $(yes file | head -n 3)
```

The command substitution `$()` expands to `cat file file file`.
This works only for filenames without whitespace and special symbols like `*`. If needed, you can set `IFS=$'\n'` and `set -o noglob`.