# what does the option Inone mean for linux command xargs?

Tags: linux, bash

I have seen the Inone option for linux command xargs ,but I googled and did not find out what the option means.

`seq 2 | xargs -Inone cat file`

[Using seq with xargs:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594074/in-linux-how-to-repeat-multiple-lines-in-a-file-in-the-same-order)

Comment: It is `-I[replace-str]`

Comment: What did you google?  Search for `man xargs` and the man page is the first hit.  Then, you RTFM.  This is twice as much work as it was before google, when you would just RTFM.  That is, you type `man xargs` directly into your shell rather than into a web browser.  Kids these days.  smh

Answer (score 1):

This is a clever use of `xargs` and `seq` to avoid writing a loop.  It  is basically the equivalent of:

```
for i in {1..2}; do
  cat file
done
```

That is, it will run `cat file` once for each line of output from the `seq` command.  The `-Inone` simply prevents `xargs` from appending the value read from `seq` to the command; see the `xargs` man page for details on the `-I` option:

```
   -I replace-str
          Replace  occurrences of replace-str in the initial-ar‐
          guments with names read from  standard  input.   Also,
          unquoted  blanks do not terminate input items; instead
          the separator is the newline  character.   Implies  -x
          and -L 1.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call avoiding an in-shell construct with multiple external processes "clever".